# Constructor and destructor Calls

Tags: c#, c++, oop

When we create an object of a derived class,
why are the constructors called in  a top-to-bottom fashion (first the  base constructor, then derived constructor) and  are destructors called bottom-to-top (first derived constructor,  then base constructor)

Comment: What would you expect to happen if class `Derived` inherited class `Base` and class `Base` had a property called `BaseProperty`.. then `Derived` tried setting that property in its constructor?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To explain for newbies, consider you are constructing a new building.

You Construct basement, first floor, 2nd floor. 
While destroying , you destroy 2nd Floor, First Floor, and basement.

The same way, construction/destruction of a object happens in C++.

Hope this helps to understand.

Comment: Thanks for example but why this hierarchy. Is there  any specific reason to follow this like some kind of data structure (Stack) is following when object is created.

Comment: Think like this: inheritance means what?. you are using something from the previous one. constructing 1st floor, before basement? it doesn't make much sense.

Comment: I agree with you but not fully satisfied because I just want to answer in terms of memory allocation or something like that means any technical reason.

Comment: Ok, in that case, kindly check @leemes comment. It is explained nicely. :).

Comment: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3617465/how-are-constructors-and-destructors-implemented-in-c?rq=1)

(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3759270/will-the-destructor-of-the-base-class-called-if-an-object-throws-an-exception-in?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

Memory allocation is independent of calling constructors and destructors. When constructing a derived object, memory for the whole type will be allocated.

Then, its constructor is called (not the base constructor). However, this constructor first calls the base class constructor. Per default, the base's default constructor gets called, but you can specify how to call the base constructor within the derived constructor. If no such exists and you don't specify how to construct the base class, it's a compile error.

```
class Base {
    int x;
public:
    Base() : x(42) {}
};

class Derived : public Base {
    int y;
public:
    Derived() : Base(), y(1337) {}
    // is the same as: Derived() {}
};
```

Here, `Base()` isn't possible (it doesn't provide a default constructor):

```
class Base {
    int x;
public:
    Base(int x) : x(x) {}
};

class Derived : public Base {
    int y;
public:
    Derived() : Base(),   y(1337) {}  // <-- error!
    Derived() : Base(42), y(1337) {}  // <-- ok!
};
```

So as you can see, technically the derived constructor is the first one being called. But since it calls the base constructor at the very beginning, it's effectively the other way around: The base is constructed, then the derived class "adds" its own stuff.

The destruction is simply the other way around: An instance of the derived class needs to clean up the stuff it adds to the base class before the base can be destructed.

Think of this simply as building a house: You have to build the base first, then add the stories, finally the roof. When destructing, first remove the roof, then the stories and finally get rid of the base.

Comment: Base constructor

Derived constructor

Derived destructor

Base destructor

I just want valid reason why this hierarchy follow

Answer (score 0):

It's the consequence of another rule: all the base constructors are called before entering the body of the derived constructor, and all the base destructors are called after leaving the body of the derived destructor.

Consider this (oversimplified) code:

```
class BaseMember
{
public:
    bool Pred();
};

class DerivedMember
{
public:
    void DoFirst(bool);
    void DoLast(bool);
};

class Base
{
public:
    Base() {baseMember=new BaseMember;}
    ~Base(){delete baseMember;}
protected:
    BaseMember *baseMember;
};

class Derived: public Base
{
public:
    Derived()
    {
        derivedMember=new DerivedMember;
        derivedMember->DoFirst(baseMember->Pred());
    }
    ~Derived()
    {
        derivedMember->DoLast(baseMember->Pred());
        delete derivedMember;
    }
protected:
    DerivedMember *derivedMember;
};
```

We can write something like that because we rely on Base being fully constructed (all the Base's bases constructors are finished, all the Base member constructors are finished too, Base's constructor body is finished) before we enter the body of Derived constructor. This way, we can use all the bases' members knowing they are constructed. When we enter the body of Derived destructor, we have knowledge that nothing has been destructed yet, so 
we can use all the bases' members knowing they still exist and will be destructed later.

Constructor/Destructor call hierarchy is the consequence of this logic. If we call Base constructor before entering the body of the Derived(), and Base itself is derived from BaseOfBase, then the Base constructor will call BaseOfBase() constructor before entering the body of Base(). If we call the ~Base() destructor after leaving the ~Derived() destructor's body, then the ~BaseOfBase() destructor will be called after the ~Base() destructor has finished.

In C++, multiple inheritance (and virtual inheritance) will complicated call hierarchy further, but the same logic applies in such cases, too.